# Game build with unity but when the game is deployed to an Android device it will suddenly close

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

We made a game and we used Unity on making it. The game is working fine in Unity but after we build it and deployed it on my Android phone, the game is not continuing and will crash seconds after playing it. Can you help us resolve this problem? We even use nox app for testing our game but still the game is always crashing.

Comment: What does logcat say? Without knowing anything about your game or what it does there's really no way to answer this question.

Comment: You can connect your mobile to the computer and run adb command as explained in this link. This way you can see the logcat and what causes the crash.
https://answers.unity.com/questions/492681/how-to-use-adb-logcat.html